# Проверка наличия детей у элемента DOM

Tags: javascript

```
if (!elem.childNodes.length) { ... }
```

Это одна из задач LearnJavaScript. Я не понимаю, зачем стоит оператор логического отрицания. Объясните пожалуйста механизм работы этого кода.

Comment: это эквивалент записи `elem.childNodes.length!=0`

Comment: @Grundy `elem.childNodes.length==0`?

Comment: @Igor, да, направления перепутал :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь применяется одна из фишек встречающихся в js на каждом шагу - механизм неявного преобразования типов.

По порядку `elem.childNodes` - это массив (на самом деле нет, но для простоты считаем что массив).
Мы смотрим длину массива. Дети есть - длина ненулевая. Нету - соответственно `elem.childNodes.length` будет равно нулю.

Получается что мы на место где должна быть логическая конструкция - подсовываем число. `if(0)` или `if(5)` там. Некоторые языки при этом угадывают, что мы пытаемся им сказать, некоторые - бросают исключение. Javascript - угадывает. Это называется "неявное преобразование типов". Подробнее Вы можете [прочитать в том же учебнике.](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion)

Вот здесь этот механизм и срабатывает:
Число мы приводим к булевому типу. Логично что 0 приводится к false, не 0 - к true.  Вот и получается что проверка `if(elements.childNodes.length)` эквивалентна `if(elements.childNodes.length != 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Если у элемента есть дети то длина свойства `childNodes` будет больше ноля , если их нету то длина будет 0 что при сравниванию будет равно `false`. Т.е. фактически если нету детей то значение `elem.childNodes.length` == 0 == false. И если нам надо чтобы условие выполнялось когда этих детей нету, т.е. значние переменной равно false, ставим отрицание на начале в итоге получаем:
`if (!false) { ... }` -> а как мы знаем `!false == true` - как раз то что нам нужно , чтобы условие сработало в момент, когда нету детей у элемента.

Comment: Спасибо, что разжевали. Я наконец-то додумался, что по задумке автора, true должно выводиться, тогда, когда элемент не имеет детей.